# Golang Gorilla Sends 301 For "//" URLs

Tags: go, gorilla

I have two route configured as following

- `GET /api/store/{store_id}/books`
- `GET /api/store/{store_id}`

When an API call comes for the first URL without `{store_id}` parameter, like `/api/store//books`, Gorilla would somehow send a `301 /api/store/books` to client. This is causing me problem because it acutally matched the second route. Gorilla would treat `books` as the `{store_id}` parameter.

How do I configure Gorilla to return 404 or other error code when receiving `//` in URLs?

I am using Gorilla v1.7.0.

Comment: as far as i am aware go replaces // with / in url's, so y0u can not have an empty store_id

Comment: If you know the pattern for `store_id`, you can add its regex. For example, if it contains only numbers, then you can change the path to `/api/store/{store_id:\d+}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default mux will clean the URL. You can set the [`router.SkipClean(true)`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.SkipClean) parameter to avoid that.

> When true, if the route path is "/path//to", it will remain with the double slash. This is helpful if you have a route like: /fetch/http://xkcd.com/534/